# How do I navigate from ShellContent/a ContentPage to a TabBar/TabbedPage in .NET MAUI Shell?

Tags: maui, .net-maui.shell, maui-shell

In my shell, I have defined a route "main". Nested underneath, I have defined a tabbar with the route "tabs". I want to navigate from my homepage to this tab page using a button. The tabpage should have a back button to get back to the homepage again (aka, I want to do relative navigation.).

When I try to do the navigation using this line of code: `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("tabs");`

... I get this error: "System.ArgumentException: 'unable to figure out route for: tabs (Parameter 'uri')'"

Below is my AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiTabShell.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiTabShell"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MauiTabShell.Pages"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="main">
        <TabBar Route="tabs">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:PageOne}" />
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:PageTwo}" />
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:PageThree}" />
        </TabBar>
    </ShellContent>
</Shell>
```

Reproduction: https://github.com/BurkusCat/MauiShellTabNavRepro

1. I have tried having the tabbar at the same level as the homepage and doing absolute navigation (`"//tabs"`) which works, but doesn't give me a back button
2. I have tried registering a `TabbedPage` in "AppShell.xaml.cs`, but [TabbedPages don't work with Shell according to Maui documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/tabbedpage)

```cs
Routing.RegisterRoute("tabs", typeof(MyTabbedPage));
```

3. I've tried creating a "TabBar" xaml and xaml.cs file in a similar way to the way you would create a ContentPage or TabbedPage. This didn't work. I tried doing this in pure CSharp too.
4. I've tried various routes such as (`"//home/tabs"`) to get the navigation to work but no joy.

I feel like this should be the most simple task but I have had no success so far and have not been able to find any good examples of this kind of navigation (the documentation and most tutorials start on a tabbar/flyout rather than trying to navigate from a homepage to a page with tabs).

Ultimately, my goal is to navigate from a ContentPage to a page with tabs. So I don't particularly care if that ends up being a TabBar or a tab page. I think I could probably skip shell for this one navigation, but then I'd lose all the dependency injection / parameter passing which would be bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell is incorrect.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/#app-visual-hierarchy

Not the navigation, the structure itself.

The correct way to implement TabBar is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs

Short answer is:

```
<TabBar>
   <Tab>
      <ShellContent>
```

Not:

```
<ShellContent>
  <TabBar>
    <ShellContent>
```

Edit: The structure you requested:

```
<ShellItem Route="HomePage">
    <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:HomePage}"/>
</ShellItem>

<TabBar>
        <Tab Route="PageOne">
          <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:PageOne}"/>
        </Tab>
        <Tab Route="PageTwo">
          <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate view:PageTwo}"/>
        </Tab>
</TabBar>
```

You can switch between them with `"//HomePage"` and `"//PageOne"`.

Comment: It makes sense that the parent "ShellContent" may be wrong. However, I'm still not sure how my Shell should look overall. I want to have a "Home" page (just a content page) with a button, when I press that button it should take me to the TabBar/page with the tabs (which should have a back button to return to the "Home" page). Where should I place my homepage in the shell and where should the tab page go (What should the routes be?)?

Comment: @BurkusCat well, I created it for you, try to understand what is going on, by reading the link I gave you again.

Comment: Thanks for the example. This was something I already tried (its no. 1 in my list of things I tried). Unfortunately, this replaces the navigation stack with just the tab page. There is no back button to get back to the homepage and pressing the Android back button closes the app. I can workaround things by trying to create my own back button + handle Android back, but I feel being able to push a tab page on top of a normal content page would be a better solution (it works in non-shell pretty easily).

Comment: @BurkusCat 3rd time I say it: READ the link I gave you. You will see that "//" navigation, clears the navigation stack. This means, that, the only page in your navigation stack is the current one. When you click "back" it removes the page, the navigation stack becomes empty, the program closes. This is the expected behavior. You need to write custom navigation and override the back button click. This is well beyond the scope of the question. Write a new question about it if you have a problem.

Comment: In my original question I asked how to do relative navigation and explained why absolute navigation wouldn't be adequate for this scenario.

The answer to my question appears to be: it isn't possible to do relative navigation from a content page to a tab page in Shell. It is only possible to do absolute navigation with workarounds to make it 'appear' like the tabs page is being navigated to relatively.

Comment: @BurkusCat Well. Not really. You can also use "///" to switch between stacks (tabs) or "/" to use relative navigation. It is not the navigation that stops you. It is the Back button function. But I do not think you should try to implement custom navigation, if you have problems with the basic one. Again, please read the link I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the solution of @H.A.H. ...
And for the back button problem, you can solve it by overriding OnBackButtonPressed

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
  BackHomeAsync();
  return true; //this blocks the app from Closing 
}

private async Task BackHomeAsync()
{
  await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
}
```

I hope this might help u.